# Cannot redeclare class in Symfony2 Twig extension

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm creating a Twig extension and activating it with a service. Everything works great except I'm trying to simply use another class from my Twig extension.

The idea is to instantiate the new class then use it as needed. Instantiating is a problem as it errors with:

```
Error: Cannot redeclare class NewClass in .../Bundle/NewClass.php line 13
```

Surely it instantiates it once. Why is this happening?

```
namespace Bundle\Twig;

use Bundle\NewClass;

class NewExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    private $request;
    private $new_class;

    public function __construct($container) {

        //get the Request object   
        $this->request = $container->get('request');

        //instantiate new class
        $this->new_class = new NewClass();  // this part triggers the error

    }

    ///etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your `NewClass` into a service and then inject that and the `@request` service into your twig extension rather than the container. Injecting the container directly is a bad idea apparently.

For example in your services..

```
services:
    # create new class as a instantiated service
    acme_demo.new_class:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\NewClass
        arguments: [ '@request' ]

    acme_demo.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
        arguments: [ '@request', '@acme_demo.new_class' ]
            # inject the Request service and your class from above
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

And then in your Twig extension

```
namespace Bundle\Twig;

use Bundle\NewClass;

class NewExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $new_class;

    public function __construct(NewClass $newClass) {
        $this->new_class = $newClass;
    }

    ///etc.
```

In your NewClass:

```
namespace Bundle;

class NewClass
{
    private $param1;
    private $param2;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->param1 = $request->get('param1');
        $this->param2 = $request->get('param2');

        // You could also add some check in here to make sure they are valid.
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks, the only thing is how do I pass in parameters to the new class as normally in PHP I would use: new NewClass($param1, $param2) etc. - all parameters are from the Request class.

Comment: You could send the request to the NewClass to get the params. I've updated my answer for that. Doesn't seem ideal though. Why do you need the request in you twig extension? Might make more sense then.